# How to Align Label and drop down list in single line in gridview

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, webforms

Here I am trying to align label and Drop down list in a single line but I am not able to do. I have tried by increasing the width of the column and decreasing the width of the Drop down but that is not solving my problem.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text="Name:" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployeeName" runat="server"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="EmployeeNameChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                                AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="20px">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Asc" Value="Asc"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Desc" Value="Desc"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("EmployeeName") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD0xv.png) Label and Drop down is coming in 2 lines but I need in a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Please apply the horizontal align to header like as below to grid header.

```
<headerstyle horizontalalign="Center" />
```

Comment: It's aligning in the center but not in single line.